# Installing Jekyll on Elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

newbie here who's been trying to install jekyll on elementary os (5.1.7 Hera) according to [this](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/ubuntu/) documentation. It all looks good up until I try `gem install jekyll bundler` at which point I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `each' for "A YAML array of remote gem repositories to install gems from":String
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:73:in `replace'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:39:in `from'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1001:in `sources'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:58:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:43:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:43:in `fetcher'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:38:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:445:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:445:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:194:in `install_gem'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:255:in `block in install_gems'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in `install_gems'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in `execute'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command.rb:313:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:173:in `process_args'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:143:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:59:in `run'
    /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Anyone know what might be going on here? Anyone had success installing jekyll on elementary os? Please pardon what I guess is a very basic question...

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your issue by doing a fresh install of Ruby and Jekyll using the installation instructions you linked. I didn't have the problem you encountered.

That said, I would try the following:

1. Try `gem install jekyll` and `gem install bundler` separately. Does the problem come up in both or just one?
2. Try uninstalling jekyll and bundler (if installed), clearing your gem paths (as described in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304552/error-while-executing-gem-nomethoderror-undefined-method-spec-for-niln)), then reinstalling jekyll and bundler.

### Additional Note

Your question appears to be related primarily to Ruby. If your issue persists, I think you might get help more easily by searching or asking on the Stack Overflow site (or a Ruby-specific alternative).